# I want to add mutiple names based on active range. Is it possible?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

I'm working with Google Sheets and Apps script. And I have added a button that gives me one Header when i Push it, in the active range (lets say "A5" is active. And i push the button a set value appears)

What I can't figure out is how to do the same thing for multiple colums.

I have looked around on youtube, done a lot of google search to try and find a way to give me some hints on how to do it. But I can't find any answer that give me any starting point.

```
\\\ function onOpen() {
  var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
   ui.createMenu('Kalkyle')
    .addItem('Sett inn layout', 'layout')
    .addToUi();
}


\\\ function layout() {



}


\\\ function nyKalkyle() {

var range1 = "Varenummer";
var range2 = "Varenavn";

SpreadsheetApp.getActiveRange().setValue(range1);
SpreadsheetApp.getActiveRange(range1 + 1 ).setValue(range2); 


}

\\\
```

ex:

Active range is A5. I push the button and A5 gets value "Varenummer". I also want it to fill inn B5, C5, D5, E5 etc with different values.

ac:

Only value "Varenummer" shows up in active range.

Comment: Try `SpreadsheetApp.getActiveRange().offset(0, 1).setValue(range2);` to set the second value in B5. When you click on a cell, it is current active range and you have to get other ranges too that you want to set values into. There are few ways to do that. See [here](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range).

Comment: And if i want to offset a row i take `SpreadsheetApp.getActiveRange().offset(1, 1).setValue(range2);` ?

Comment: Yes that's it :)

Comment: Is it possible to set formula that will follow the active range? Not be set on E2 if the active range is A20.

Comment: Are you trying to set/unset formula on a cell based on value in active or another cell ? If so, this is possible.

Comment: `SpreadsheetApp.getActiveRange().offset(6, 4).setFormula('=ArrayFormula(IF(C7;D7*F7+(E7/1*D7*F7);""))').setNumberFormat("0.00 KR"); ` Like this. I want the row numbers to get in if the user changes activeRange and push the button.

Comment: Do not keep asking (or answering, @ra89fi) new questions in comments. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask Questions should reflect effort on behalf of the asker, including own research and attempts. If you want an interactive dialog with each other, use chat.

Comment: I'm sorry @tehhowch.  I can't use chat because I'm new here. And I always try to do reasearch as much as I can. I have been working a lot the past couple of weeks on a script, and have always manage to find a answer, until today. That's the reason why I made a account here and asked.

Comment: There's nothing wrong with having questions and seeking answers to them. But on Stack Overflow, one question should be a fairly specific issue, and the text of that question should include results of code attempts and research you've done to try to resolve that issue. You can understand then, that comments are not suited for asking, because you cannot demonstrate the effort you have put in to attempting to resolve the issue on your own.